# Large values (Inf) in raw depth map

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, depth-map

[image]I render depth maps, in Cycles, in OpenEXR format (because I need the actual distances) and later read them in python using the openexr package.
I save the depth maps like this: Connect 'Depth' of RenderLayers node to 'FileOutput' node for which in turn I set output format to 32-bit OpenEXR and enable 'Zbuf'.

For some of the scenes (not all) I have, I notice that the depth maps have large values like Inf or 1e10.  Normally, should the value get clipped to the distance of the far plane?  How do I correct for this?